# Why does a syntax error occur after restart?

Tags: javascript, object, promise

I'm running my little testsite on localhost (although currently there isn't even serverside interaction yet). 
Everything worked fine until I restarted my PC. Oo

Now, when running the site, the following error is thrown:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token new

Here's the code:

```js
let promise1 = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('string1');
})

 function starter (){
  promise1.then(new Promise (stringParam1) => {
    //if(stringParam1){
    console.log("stringParam1 is ", stringParam1);
       setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("timeout was executed")
        return stringParam1 + 'string2'
      }, 1000)
/*    }else{
      return 'fail1'
    }*/

  }).then((stringParam2) => {
    console.log("stringParam2 is ", stringParam2)
    return stringParam2 + 'string3'
  }).then((stringParam3) => {
    console.log(stringParam3)
  })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP is Awesome!</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "MyFirstPhP.css">
    </head>
        <body>
            <button onclick="starter()">promise</button>
            <p id = "output">testoutput</p>
            <script src="MyFirstPhP.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What line does the error refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a parenthesis.  You also never resolve a promise in your setTimeout function.

```js
let promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('string1');
})

function starter() {
  promise1.then(stringParam1 => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("stringParam1 is ", stringParam1);
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("timeout was executed")
      resolve(stringParam1 + 'string2')
    }, 1000)
  })).then((stringParam2) => {
    console.log("stringParam2 is ", stringParam2)
    return stringParam2 + 'string3'
  }).then((stringParam3) => {
    console.log(stringParam3)
  })
}

starter();
```

Async/Await will really make this cleaner. It will reduce nesting and parentheses, and make your code easier to read and reuse.

```js
let promise1 = async() => {
  return 'string1';
}

let promise2 = (param) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("stringParam1 is ", param);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("timeout was executed")
    resolve(param + 'string2')
  }, 1000)
})

let promise3 = async(param) => {
  return param + 'string3'
}

async function starter() {
  let stringParam1 = await promise1()
  let stringParam2 = await promise2(stringParam1)
  console.log("stringParam2 is ", stringParam2)
  let stringParam3 = await promise3(stringParam2)
  console.log(stringParam3)
}

starter()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues, not just syntax related. First in your start function you are modifying the data that is resolved in `promise` inside of an async operation (`setTimeout`) so you can't return anything and instead need to call resolve/reject. The `new Promise()` should be returned inside of an anonymous function which is provided your value from `promise`.

Then inside of your `starter` function you can modify what is returned in the subsequent `then` methods. The starter function will now return a promise with the wrapped and modified value which is currently `undefined` since nothing is returned in your anonymous function as the argument to the last `then` method of the promise chain.

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('string1')
})

function starter() {
  return promise.then((stringParam1) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log('stringParam1 is ', stringParam1)
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('timeout was executed')
        resolve(stringParam1 + 'string2')
      }, 1000)
    })
  }).then((stringParam2) => {
    console.log('stringParam2 is ', stringParam2)
    return stringParam2 + 'string3'
  }).then((stringParam3) => {
    console.log(stringParam3)
  })
}

starter();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code missed paranthesis around the `promise1.then` lambda.
Here is the fixed code :

```
let promise1 = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('string1');
})

 function starter (){
  promise1.then(new Promise ((stringParam1) => {
    //if(stringParam1){
    console.log("stringParam1 is ", stringParam1);
       setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("timeout was executed")
        return stringParam1 + 'string2'
      }, 1000)
/*    }else{
      return 'fail1'
    }*/

  })).then((stringParam2) => {
    console.log("stringParam2 is ", stringParam2)
    return stringParam2 + 'string3'
  }).then((stringParam3) => {
    console.log(stringParam3)
  })
}
```

Comment: Your call to `promise1.then()` should actually take an anonymous function which is provided the value when resolved.

Comment: Yes that's right, but my answer only adressed the syntax issue.